# How to prove this just by using Natural Deduction?

Tags: predicate-logic, quantifiers, natural-deduction

I need your help to prove this  by using Natural Deduction:
$$(\exists x)(p(x) \implies q) \dashv\vdash (\forall x)(p(x) \implies q).$$
I want to  show the proof  for both sides. It is a bit easy for me to get the first side from the second side. How can I get the right side from the left side by just using Natural Deduction. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Not the same question. The other one is true, this isn't.

Comment: It was just by chance i really dont know who posted it before me, i know it is hard to believe but it is really so

Comment: I think you want $(\exists x\; p(x)) \Rightarrow q$, not $\exists x\; (p(x) \Rightarrow q)$.

Comment: @user43208 I am sure about that. That is what make me stacked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right hand side does not follow from the left hand side.  If $p(x_1)$ is false, $p(x_2)$ is true, and $q$ is false, then $p(x_1) \implies q$ is true but $p(x_2) \implies q$ is false.

Comment: I think you mean the right side does not follow from the left.

Comment: @dfeuer Thanks, I fixed it.